# Jenkins Sonarqube scanner results not display

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I have installed the sonarqube scanner plugin in jenkins and added the below properties in execute sonarqube scanner in the build section of jenkins instance.

```
# Project identification
sonar.projectKey=BUS.App
sonar.projectVersion=Test
sonar.projectName=BUS App

# Info required for Sonar 
sonar.sources=.
sonar.language=cs 

#Core C# Settings
sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file=BUS.Platform2.sln
sonar.dotnet.excludeGeneratedCode=true

#----- Default source code encoding
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

After the build completion of the instance in sonar server it shows the correct analysis time but doesn't shows the analytics results.

I did the analysis in my project using SonarMSBuild (not in jenkins locally in the project folder), it shows the results correctly.

This is how the sonar server after jekins build.
[image: sonar results]

Does my sonar scanner properties are wrong? or did I missed something?

This is how my build section looks in jenkins configure.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you analyze C#. As [described in the docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMSBuild) You need

- SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild - Begin Analysis
- Build
- SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild - End Analysis

You'll pass a couple properties in to the Begin Analysis step, but by and large you don't need those properties.

And you particularly don't need `sonar.language` which was deprecated years ago.

Comment: I tried that MSBuild thing, but it didn't worked, that's why I tried this. Is it not possible to analyse C# project using this method?

Comment: It is not @PMArtz

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeamit works fine now, there was an issue with my MSBuild. Fixed that.